# How to disable large popups when typing in Pycharm?

Tags: pycharm

[image]

I always get this when I'm coding, and it's extremely annoying. How would I go about turning this thing off? Is it an inspection?

Oh and just in case you can't see the picture, just click on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was annoying for me too, but follow these steps to disable it:

File > Settings or  (press ctrl+alt+s for windows)

Editor > General > Code Completion

**Uncheck** > Show the parameter info popup

Apply

Comment: I'm finding the auto-suggest feature annoying. It keeps suggesting things when I'm writing tests, so I type any number character and up pops an infinite selection of pointless options meaning I have to click "esc" just to get rid of it each time.